# Win 10: Block specific process from deleting file

Tags: windows, permissions

I'm admining a render farm. The farm has its own service account which has local admin permissions.  We use an app that has a bug which deletes a file and prevents itself from working correctly.  I want to block a specific process from deleting a specific file. I don't care how this is achieved user rights, cheetah blood...

The catch is that the app needs to have admin rights granted for other purposes.  I tried changing user rights and file attributes, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **Deny Delete** permission on the file for the user account under which the app runs. Even if the account has Administrative permissions, the Deny permission will have its effect. The only way a user with full administrative permissions can override an explicit deny permission is if the application specifically modifies the permissions on the file to *remove* the deny permission before deleting it.

If the bug in your application is doing that, you've got bigger fish to fry.